# When does python's Pool fork?

Tags: python

Does anybody know at which stage python's Pool forks the main process?
On pool creation, or on first job run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `multiprocessing.Pool` objects is created it spawns some threads but it does not fork. The forking is done when calling the other `Pool` methods, and only on UNIX systems(on Windows there is no fork).

You can see this reading the `Pool.__init__` method's source code:

```
class Pool(object):
    '''
    Class which supports an async version of applying functions to arguments.
    '''
    Process = Process

    def __init__(self, processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=(),
                 maxtasksperchild=None):
        self._setup_queues()
        self._taskqueue = queue.Queue()
        self._cache = {}
        self._state = RUN
        self._maxtasksperchild = maxtasksperchild
        self._initializer = initializer
        self._initargs = initargs

        if processes is None:
            try:
                processes = cpu_count()
            except NotImplementedError:
                processes = 1
        if processes < 1:
            raise ValueError("Number of processes must be at least 1")

        if initializer is not None and not callable(initializer):
            raise TypeError('initializer must be a callable')

        self._processes = processes
        self._pool = []
        self._repopulate_pool()

        self._worker_handler = threading.Thread(
            target=Pool._handle_workers,
            args=(self, )
            )
        self._worker_handler.daemon = True
        self._worker_handler._state = RUN
        self._worker_handler.start()


        self._task_handler = threading.Thread(
            target=Pool._handle_tasks,
            args=(self._taskqueue, self._quick_put, self._outqueue, self._pool)
            )
        self._task_handler.daemon = True
        self._task_handler._state = RUN
        self._task_handler.start()

        self._result_handler = threading.Thread(
            target=Pool._handle_results,
            args=(self._outqueue, self._quick_get, self._cache)
            )
        self._result_handler.daemon = True
        self._result_handler._state = RUN
        self._result_handler.start()

        self._terminate = Finalize(
            self, self._terminate_pool,
            args=(self._taskqueue, self._inqueue, self._outqueue, self._pool,
                  self._worker_handler, self._task_handler,
                  self._result_handler, self._cache),
            exitpriority=15
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have another one :)
In my code I create the pool, then I have some logic that loads staff to the memory, and then I throw jobs to the pool and iterate over it with imap_unsorted. From your answer I see that the fork happens AFTER the logic that loads staff to the memory, and it's bad, since I duplicate this staff into all worker sub-processes. Do you know how can I avoid it (i.e. force the fork BEFORE I start loading staff to memory)? Thanks!!!

Comment: @diemacht I think you should pass the [`initializer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) parameter of the `Pool` object. It should be a function called to initialize the workers, and it seems the right place to do what you want.